# How to check the LLVM compiler version Xcode is using?

Tags: xcode, llvm

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 on OS X 10.8.2. How do I know which version of LLVM compiler Xcode is using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From UI:

- Click on your project
- Choose a target (it may be choosen by default)
- Click on Build Settings tab
- Scroll it to see "Apple LLVM complier: X.X - Code generation"

X.X is version of your LLVM

Comment: That's Apple internal version of LLVM. Here I found how to get actual LLVM version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552782/llvm-version-on-ios-and-android

Answer (score 29):

From the command line:

```
07:40:35 andrew@iMac SalesIQ (siq-303)$ llvm-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 - enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
07:40:39 andrew@iMac SalesIQ (siq-303)$
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, terminal shows version 4.2.1, while Xcode seems to be using 4.1?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your build settings; you have a choice of Clang or llvm-gcc, and an iOS build may use a different one from OSX.  To see exactly which version was used, expand a compile selection of a build log for something like “`Compile ViewController.m`.”  There will be a line like “`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x …`”

or

“`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x…`”

Select the path to the compiler, and in Terminal execute the following:

```
8> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang --version

Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)…
```

or

```
9> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 --version

i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2410.2.00)…
```

Note that the Apple Clang versioning is distinct from both the GCC versioning and the open-source LLVM.