# LLVM version on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, llvm

How to find out which LLVM version is used in Android NDK and Apple Xcode?

Checking `clang --version` from Android NDK r15c I got:

```
Android clang version 5.0.300080  (based on LLVM 5.0.300080)
```

but NDK r15c was released in July 2017, before actual release of LLVM 5.0 (what happened in September 2017). Does it really use LLVM 5.0?

Checking `clang --version` from Xcode only shows Apple's own LLVM version:

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
```

is there any way to find out to which "unpatched" LLVM version it relates?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39076986/598057.

Comment: Thanks, but the info there is a bit outdated (Apple LLVM 7.0.x => LLVM 3.x)

Comment: True, the latest is [800.0.42.1](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-800.0.42.1/src/) which is 3.9.0 if judging on CMakeLists.

Comment: You can ask on [llvm-dev](http://lists.llvm.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/lldb-dev) forum to get the best answer.

Comment: "the latest is 800.0.42.1 which is 3.9.0", and the actual version reported from clang binary is 900.0.38, hope we have 4.0 update at least :) and thank you I will try to use the forum as well

Comment: Yes, I meant latest available on opensource.apple. Please post back the answer here if you get it on llvm-dev - your question is very good :)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955807/whats-is-proper-version-of-llvm-clang-xcode?rq=1.

Comment: Yes, sure :) I will post the answer if find the info!

Comment: And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421690/what-is-my-version-of-llvm-clang-osx?rq=1. Find your answer and then we can mark all other answers as duplicates of yours (they are mostly outdated, do not have a good answer).

Comment: Not exactly duplicate, because I'm asking about Android as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Android.** Accordingly to the LLVM source code for Android NDK: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/google/stable/, it seems that NDK r15c really uses [LLVM 5.0](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/google/stable/2017-07-18/) (as contained in CMakeLists.txt).

And right after that release they switched to unreleased yet [LLVM 6.0](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/google/stable/2017-08-02/). So it seems that Google tries to use in NDK the latest LLVM version available.

**2) iOS.** For the Xcode, guys from llvm-dev maillist suggested to look at the branches of swift-llvm repository: https://github.com/apple/swift-llvm
- accordingly to that, Swift 4.0 (as well as the current Xcode 9.1 version) uses LLVM 4.0 and the upcoming release of Swift 4.1 (in 2018) will use at least LLVM 5.0.

Answer (score -1):

but it was created by **llvm5.0.1**，can not be read by `LLVM` of `NDK r15c。`

> error: Invalid value (Producer: 'LLVM5.0.1' Reader: 'LLVM 5.0.300080')